# How to update text using TextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having some troubles trying to figure out how to edit a text thats already been made.

I have done most of the things and the one i'm stuck at is the button that updates the text to the new updated text. I can see the updated text when I use console.log but it doesn't update the text. Thats still the same. Below you can see the full code and I think the updateTodo function is done wrong.

```
export default function App() {
  const [updateTaskId, setUpdateTaskId] = useState('');
  const [updateTaskTitle, setUpdateTaskTitle] = useState('');
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const updateTodo = () => {
    const todoAsync = [
      ...todos,
      {
        key: updateTaskId,
        name: updateTaskTitle,
      },
    ];
    setTodos(todoAsync);
  };

  const renderitem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: colors.card,
          margin: 10,
          elevation: 1,
          borderRadius: 10,
          padding: 10,
        }}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Fontisto
            name={item.isChecked ? 'checkbox-active' : 'checkbox-passive'}
            size={20}
            color={colors.text}
            onPress={() => checkTodo(item.key)}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            onLongPress={() => {
              setUpdateModal(true);
              setUpdateTaskTitle(item.name);
            }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: colors.text,
                marginLeft: 20,
                marginRight: 20,
              }}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10}}>
          <Fontisto name="date" size={20} color={colors.text} />
          <Text style={{marginLeft: 20, color: colors.text}}>{item.date}</Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 10,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
          }}>
          <Feather
            name={item.notification ? 'bell-off' : 'bell'}
            size={20}
            color={colors.text}
            onPress={() => checkNotification(item.key)}
          />
          <Fontisto
            name="trash"
            size={20}
            color={colors.text}
            onPress={() => {
              setModalVisible(true);
              setDetails(item);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.background}}>
      <Modal
        hardwareAccelerated={true}
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={true}
        visible={updateModal}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setUpdateModal(!updateModal);
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: colors.Modal,
              padding: 35,
              borderRadius: 10,
              width: '80%',
              height: '40%',
            }}>
            <View style={{}}>
              <TextInput
                style={{backgroundColor: colors.background, marginTop: 10}}
                onChangeText={name => setUpdateTaskTitle(name)}
                value={updateTaskTitle}
              />
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                marginTop: 50,
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  setUpdateModal(false);
                  setUpdateTaskTitle('');
                }}>
                <Text>Close</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  setUpdateModal(false);
                  updateTodo(...todos, {name: updateTaskTitle});
                  setUpdateTaskTitle('');
                  console.log(updateTaskTitle);
                }}>
                <Text>Update</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <Modal
        hardwareAccelerated={true}
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: colors.Modal,
              padding: 35,
              borderRadius: 10,
              width: '80%',
              height: '40%',
            }}>
            <View>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: colors.text}}>Delete?</Text>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                marginTop: 15,
              }}>
              <Text style={{color: colors.text}}>Completed: </Text>
              <Fontisto
                style={{marginLeft: 20}}
                name={
                  details.isChecked ? 'checkbox-active' : 'checkbox-passive'
                }
                size={15}
                color={colors.text}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 20}}>
              <Text style={{color: colors.text}}>Title: </Text>
              <Text
                numberOfLines={1}
                style={{marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15, color: colors.text}}>
                {details.name}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <Text style={{marginTop: 20, color: colors.text}}>
              Created: {details.date}
            </Text>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                marginTop: 30,
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  setModalVisible(false);
                  setDetails('');
                }}>
                <Text style={{color: colors.text}}>Close</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  deleteTodo(details.key);
                  setModalVisible(false);
                  setDetails('');
                }}>
                <Text style={{color: colors.text}}>Delete</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding: 20,
          backgroundColor: colors.Textinput,
          elevation: 12,
        }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 5,
          }}
          placeholder="What Tododay?"
          placeholderTextColor="#000"
          onChangeText={value => setTitle(value)}
          value={title}
          autoCapitalize="words"
        />
        <Entypo
          style={{
            marginLeft: 1,
            padding: 13,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            height: 49,
            borderTopRightRadius: 5,
            borderBottomRightRadius: 5,
          }}
          name="add-to-list"
          size={25}
          color="#000"
          onPress={() => addTodo()}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          data={todos}
          renderItem={renderitem}
          ListEmptyComponent={emptyListComponent}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: In the other related functions you're setting and storing todos, but in update you're only setting them. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: @kristinalustig I mean the text would still update wouldn't it? The updated text doens't replace the old text. I can see the updated text in console.log so that makes me think the updateTodo function is wrong and this is wrong `updateTodo(...todos, {name: updateTaskTitle});`

Comment: Honestly I don't know a lot about react :D, I was just poking around recent questions and thought that might help. Do you need to pass the updateTaskId into updateTodo as well as the name? Because you're printing out the correct updateTaskTitle, I think you're right in that the problem is in updateTodo.

Comment: @kristinalustig When I set `updateTodo(updateTaskTitle, {name: updateTaskTitle});` It just adds another todo with the same id but with the updated text :l

Comment: OH wait, you're using the same code as you use to add a todo. I think you need to search through the existing todos to find the one with the correct id, and set the name appropriately. Right now you're just appending a new one to the end.

Comment: I recommend writing up your own answer to your problem so that others who find this question in the future will also be able to benefit from it! Congrats.

Comment: @kristinalustig i didnt fix it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do.

1. make a copy of all todos
2. filter out the todo that you are about to update out of the todos array
3. concat a new todo with the new text to the array of todos
4. it should render as expected

```
  const updateTodo = () => {
    const todoAsync = [
      ...todos,
    ].filter((item) => item.id !== updateTaskId).concat([{
        key: updateTaskId,
        name: updateTaskTitle,
      }])
    setTodos(todoAsync);
  };
```

Try this if you want to keep the same todo on the screen but only update the object key for name.

```
  const updateTodo = () => {
    const todoAsync = [
      ...todos,
    ].map((item) => { 
        const { key } = item;
        if(key === updateTaskId} {
         // return updated object
          return { 
              key,
              name: updateTaskTitle,
          }
        }
        else return item;
     }    
    setTodos(todoAsync);
  };
```

Comment: Is this right `updateTodo(updateTaskId, {name: updateTaskTitle});` it still adds a new todo with the same id but with the updated text.

Comment: when you update a todo you need to know the id of which todo you are updating. That way you can remove it from the array and then append a new todo with the updated name.

Comment: I'm grabbing the id of the todo with setUpdateTaskId(item.key). When i'm pressing the update button its just adding a new todo with the same id but with the updated text.